# vector::erase() not working as expected

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

```
  for(it1=prime.begin();it1<prime.end();it1++){
        for(it2=it1+1;it2<prime.end();it2++){

            if(*it2%*it1==0){

                prime.erase(it2);
            }

        }
        if(*it1<1000)
        prime.erase(it1);
    }
```

In above code snippet i am removing numbers that are multiples of number already existing in prime vector 2 to 9999(sieve of Eratosthenes).also I only what numbers that are more then 1000, but somehow these are not getting erased.

can someone please explain me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you erase them if they're LESS than 1000.

Comment: @Meke He wants numbers `>= 1000`, so he erases numbers `< 1000`. You probably misread the question.

Comment: Umm, I'll go with 'maybe'. ;)

Comment: @Meke It makes sense that he discards the primes under 1000, but it would make no sense to erase the primes over 1000 or else he would just calculate the primes under 1000 and be done.

Comment: The confusion arose in "I only what numbers that are more then 1000, but somehow these are not getting erased."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `erase()` invalidates the iterator. You should use the return value, which is an iterator to the value after the element that was deleted, e.g.

```
it2 = prime.erase(it2);
```

But if you make this change (which you must!), you need to remove `++it2` from the for loop. You also need to make both changes for `it1`. Here is some untested code:

```
for (it1 = prime.begin(); it1 < prime.end();) {
    for(it2 = it1 + 1; it2 < prime.end();) {
        if (*it2 % *it1 == 0)
            it2 = prime.erase(it2);
        else
            ++it2;
    }
    if (*it1 < 1000)
        it1 = prime.erase(it1);
    else
        ++it1;
}
```

Note that erasing `it2` will *not* invalidate `it1`, because it occurs strictly *before* `it2` due to the `it2 = it1 + 1`. So you don't need to concern yourself with that interference.

Comment: In that case you must avoid incrementing `it2++` again in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to erase item and loop, you need do 'it1=prime.begin();' again after erasing. Because of the arrangement.

Comment: Wroong. Possible, but very sub-optimal; see marcog's answer.

Comment: Oops! maybe I say it unsuitable. and need change to 'it2=prime.begin();'. I think if remove the it2 and then it2++ will jump an item. So will losing some item for 'if (*it2 % *it1 == 0)'.